# Do there exist intervals for confidence not focussed on the mean values?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Do there exist concepts of confidence intervals not focused on the mean value? In particular would the following be well defined and for which kinds of distributions would it exist?

**Maximally compact** confidence intervals, which for one dimension is a function of the distribution with density function $p$ and $k$ (the confidence): $$[a,b](p,k) = \min_{\int_a^bp(x)dx = k} \{|a-b|\}$$
So the function gives the pair $a$ and $b$ out for any 
$$k \in [0,1] \hspace{0.5cm}\textrm{and}\hspace{0.5cm} p(x) : \int^\infty_{-\infty} p(x)dx = 1$$

And for multivariate ones would minimize the integral of the 1-function over the set (that is the most reasonable extension I could think of).

I have some faint idea that fundamental theorem of calculus could be used here (in the 1-dimensional case at least), but maybe all of this has already been done and I can just read up on it somewhere rather than re-discovering it?

Comment: Are you asking if there are confidence intervals for values other than the mean? Maximally compact intervals would require unimodal distributions, unless you allow your confidence interval to be a confidence set of disjoint intervals.

Comment: Other than having the mean (or what is being estimated)  (point-estimate?) in the center of the interval. I realize that sometimes the interval of a maximally compact may not be unique for example multi-modal where several of the modes are identical.

Comment: Confidence intervals are connected with inference. They provide a range of plausible values for some quantity being estimated. Therefore, your point estimate should always be inside the CI. However, not all CIs are symmetric, and hence will not have the point estimate at the center, if that is what you mean.

Comment: Yes I was thinking if it be possible to instead of fixing around the point estimate but rather focused at some other property like any unique "most compact" integral of probability (if such exists).

Comment: A lot of confidence intervals are highest likelihood intervals. These will be asymmetric for asymmetric distributions.